# How to add my program to macOS right click menu for files and folders?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, registry, finder

I have made an C++ Qt based application for Windows and have added the option to right click a file/folder in Windows Explorer and select "Upload with myProgram", which opens `myProgram.exe` and pass the path of the clicked file/folder as `argv[1]`. I have achieved this by adding a key to the Windows registry.

Now I want to port my application to macOS.

I wonder *if* and *how* I am able to migrate the right click option to macOS, so that it works on any OS version.

I already googled a lot, but nothing really fits my problem, since I want to add the right click option programmatically when installing the application and not manually in Finder afterwards. Other SO questions concerning this issue are several years old and are not applicable anymore.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: AFAIK (but I'm not a macOS developer) you're out of luck. Apple deliberately disallows applications to automatically add anything to the Finder's context menu. You might _try_ to automate this with a script but I doubt it'll ever be sufficiently reliable and stable.

Comment: officially you can't. But Dropbox for example somehow managed to do that. For the quick solution, you can do as @AdrianoRepetti suggested, with scripts. otherwise, you should be familiar with code ingestion, but I think solving the problem with code ingestion will take a while

Comment: The idea is to inject Finder with code that accesses the menu, adds the action you need, and then executes it when triggered.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I guess i will try to implement it with a script, I am not used to mac programming at all so it would be way to difficult for me to do some kind of code ingestion. Do you have any useful links for me that teach me how do write a script like this?

Comment: The answers given are completely incorrect. It is perfectly possible to create custom Context Menu items in the Finder on macOS. You'll have to create a Finder Extension through Xcode and code some Objective-C to interface with your C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [finder extensions](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/extensions/finder-sync-extensions/) to do this. If you need more flexibility, you can use notifications to communicate with the main app and change right click menu items dynamically. [Here](https://samiyuru.com/project/macOS-finder-right-click-menu) is an app that uses the approach to add custom right click menu items. The page has a link to the source.